# How to redirect wordpress url by changing .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Hi I m trying to redirect the url from

%category%/%postname%.html  to %year%/%month%/%postname%

I tried by changing the .htaccess file but could not help.

at least i tried to redirect 
%category%/%postname%.html  to %postname% , this also didnot work

RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+).html$ http://www.example.com/$2

any help really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks ? WordPress has means to help you through this (and manually doing it on .htaccess may break your existing WP set up anyway).